# ASP.NET MVC 4 Development: what is a right choice of tools?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm going to start some ASP.NET MVC4 development, with a possibility of mixing in MVC4 parts into our big existing ASP and ASP.NET (Web Forms) application.
Our small team is currently using Visual Studio 2010 (we have MSDN subscription), developers machines are Windows 7, test machines are MS Windows Server 2003 R2 , production is hosted on MS Windows Server 2008 R2.

1. Is it possible to develop and host MVC4 pages in such environment?
2. Can I install MVC4 on Visual Studio 2010?
3. In case I have to migrate to VS 2012, would it be possible to share projects with rest of the team sitting on VS 2010 through our Team Foundation Server?
4. Can I have both VS 2010 and VS 2012 co-existing on the same machine?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, mvc4 should run even on iis6 http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx
2. Yes http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4 (See installation section)
3. No need. And vs2012 will upgrade your project file but it should be compatible with vs2010sp1 (conditions apply) http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/03/28/round-tripping-with-visual-studio-11.aspx
4. Yes

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes its possible
2. Yes you can install MVC4 without a problem in visual 2010 http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4
3. You dont need to migrate if you dont want to.
4. Yes i have installed both on my computer and work on both without a problem.